# Placing pseudocode between paragraphs

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode

I am trying to re-write a line of an algorithm's pseudocode, and I would like to be able to present it in-text rather than introducing another floating `algorithm` environment. How can I do this?

Here is an example of exactly what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Edit: I have the following MWE. I'd like to remove the horizontal lines and include numbering like the above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

...we can replace the update from Line 8 in Algorithm 3 with the following:

\begin{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \ForAll {$x \in X$}
            \State $y \leftarrow x$
        \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic} 
\end{algorithm}

This modification allows for...

\end{document}
```

Comment: What package do you use to write your pseudocode?

Comment: @Werner `algpseudocode`

Comment: @Dallan: I would assume you have those exact lines in a larger algorithm somewhere else, and you in-text referencing is meant to *exactly* replicate the indentation and numbering of the original algorithm. Correct?

Comment: just use algorithmic without the surrounding algorithm, just as for a table you would use tabular without the surrounding table

Comment: @Werner No, I was not clear. I have a larger algorithm with one line that I would like to replace with several. The new lines have not previously appeared. In the image, line 11 is replaced with 11a, 11b, and 11c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following as a template-like approach to adjust components of your algorithm. The idea is to update the line numbering scheme (with a `\ref` prefix) to print in `\alph` rather than `\arabic`, and also indent to the appropriate depth so as to match the position (horizontally) in the original algorithm.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{Euclid's algorithm}\label{alg:euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a, b$}\Comment{The g.c.d.\ of~$a$ and~$b$}
       \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
       \While{$r \neq 0$}\Comment{We have the answer if~$r$ is~$0$}
          \State $a \gets b$
          \State $b \gets r$\label{alg:b_r}
          \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
       \EndWhile
       \State \Return $b$\Comment{The gcd is~$b$}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\ldots we can replace the update from Line~\ref{alg:b_r} in Algorithm~\ref{alg:euclid} with the following:

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \renewcommand\alglinenumber[1]{\footnotesize \ref{alg:b_r}\alph{ALG@line}:}% Update line number to be \alph with prefix
    \expandafter\addtolength\csname ALG@tlm\endcsname{2\dimexpr\algorithmicindent}% Update current indentation
    \ForAll {$x \in X$}
      \State $y \leftarrow x$
    \EndFor
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

This modification allows for\ldots

\end{document}
```

If you don't want the horizontal rules, then just drop the `algorithm` environment surrounding the `algorithmic` environment. Hopefully it doesn't float elsewhere. If that happens, one could insert the horizontal rules manually, unless you have a different algorithm float style.

Comment: This works great! Thank you